# prove that the functional is $\alpha$-elliptic

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, gateaux-derivative

I got a nonlinear functional who is convex and Gâteaux differentiable. Is there some property of these two that can bring me that the functional is $\alpha$-elliptic???

Comment: Can you define $\alpha$-convex for us, please?

Comment: Sorry, I mean $\alpha$-ellipticity $$\big\langle J'\left(u\right)-J'\left(v\right),u-v\big\rangle\geq\alpha\|u-v\|^2_{X}\,,\;\forall\;u,v\in X.$$

Comment: Ah, strongly convex functions. Check the books by Borwein-Vanderwerff and by Zalinescu.

Comment: My functional is coercive, convex and Gateaux differentiable. This can't bring me some strong convexity? without the definition?

Comment: Maybe not. Have you looked at $|x|^p$ for $1<p<+\infty$?